# MySQL grouping (newest first for each "group")

Tags: mysql

I've been struggling with this one for a while now, and it seems so simple yet I can't wrap my head around it.

My initial query is as follows

```
SELECT `updated`, `price`, `condition` 
FROM game_prices 
WHERE `game_id` = '1960' 
AND `source` = '0' 
AND `updated` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
ORDER BY `updated` DESC;
```

This gives the following results...

```
updated     price   condition
1496691650  9.89    1
1496009100  0.01    0
1494799503  5.99    1
1489881902  9.89    1
1487808171  7.66    1
```

Perfect. However, what I'd like to do is select only the **most recent** of each unique "condition". Condition can be 0, 1, or 2.

To confirm **updated** is a unix timestamp.

So I perform a sub-query on the results of the initial query...

```
SELECT `updated`, `price`, `condition` 
FROM ( 
        SELECT `updated`, `price`, `condition` 
        FROM game_prices 
        WHERE `game_id` = '1960' 
        AND `source` = '0' 
        AND `updated` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
        ORDER BY `updated` DESC 
    ) AS sub 
GROUP BY `condition` 
ORDER BY `price` ASC;
```

In my head this should work, but I am getting the following results...

```
updated     price   condition
1496009100  0.01    0
1487808171  7.66    1
```

As you can see, it is picking the **oldest** record for each "condition". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It a lot easier to debug what you can see without scrolling to infinity and beyond. Please in future format your questions to be readable, it will make more people bother to stop and look at your question

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly and my apologies for the bad formatting. I will not make that same mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT gp.*
FROM game_prices gp
WHERE game_id = '1960' AND
      source = '0' AND
      updated > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND
      updated = (SELECT MAX(gp2.updated)
                 FROM game_prices gp2
                 WHERE gp2.game_id = gp.game_id AND
                       gp2.source = gp.source AND
                       gp2.condition = gp.condition AND
                       gp2.updated > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
                )
ORDER BY `updated` DESC;
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way without subqueries

```
SELECT MAX(`updated`), SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`price` ORDER BY updated DESC),',',1), `condition` 
FROM game_prices 
WHERE `game_id` = '1960' 
AND `source` = '0' 
AND `updated` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
GROUP BY `condition`
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`price` ORDER BY updated DESC),',',1) ;
```

As to your last query,you don`t have aggregate conditions on your 2 columns not in the GROUP BY,so you get indeterminate values(random)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the most logical option.

Comment: The only problem I see is that it's not possible to `ORDER BY price ASC` correctly.

Comment: @DanielCrocker Just add price in order by.

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately.

`1495404306 4.00 0`
`1492380306 25.00 1`
`1489190710 19.96 2`

Comment: @DanielCrocker What type is the column price?

Comment: That column is decimal(7,2)

Comment: Sadly not @Mihai. I think I can see the problem however. The resulting column names are:
`MAX(\`updated\`)` and
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(\`price\` ORDER BY updated DESC),',',1)` and
`condition`